# Unable to embed delimiter when converting XML to CSV using XSLT using Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, csv

I am trying to convert XML to CSV using XSLT. I have seen many similar posts on this site, but wanted to mention specific requirement and the issue I am seeing in my code.

This is my well formed XML file content. Please note, I am getting this XML from the database as a string, so it is not formatted.

XML file

```
<myxml ver="1.0"><name>smile</name><email>test@gmail.com</email><phone_number/><job_title>Engineer</job_title><company_name>Stack Overflow</company_name><submission-datestamp>3/14/11 8:29 PM</submission-datestamp></myxml>
```

Here is the XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/> 

<xsl:template match="myxml">
  <xsl:for-each select="*" >    
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>,
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting below CSV format content:

```
smile,
    test@gmail.com,
    ,
    Engineer,
    Stack Overflow,
    3/14/11 8:29 PM
```

Requirement is:

- I need to display the header first
- Comma separated list as in

  smiletest@gmail.com,EngineerStack Overflow,3/14/11 8:29 PM

Can you please help me fix my code? The problem is in XSLT file.

Comment: Well you have no elements in the source with either the name `catalog` or `cd`, so your XSLT matches nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the extra carriage returns because you have mixed-content inside of the template. The stylesheet assumes that the whitespace following the comma is significant. You can prevent that by putting your text inside of `<xsl:text>`. That tells the stylesheet which text is explicitly part of the output, so if there is nothing else left but whitespace, it is assumed to be insignificant.

I reworked the stylesheet slightly to be more of a "push style" stylesheet using `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:for-each`, and also added carriage-return at the end of each line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="text"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="header"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myxml/*" mode="header">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="myxml/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following output:

```
name,email,phone_number,job_title,company_name,submission-datestamp
smile,test@gmail.com,,Engineer,Stack Overflow,3/14/11 8:29 PM
```